# Mysql - Multiple Sum Functions in query

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a query that has several sum functions that are the same.  Would it be more efficient to run a separate sum query then bind it to my original query as a value to speed it up?

My current query

```
$dbquery = $dbh->prepare("
SELECT amount - (Select SUM(amountused) from tblamountused) as amountleft
FROM tblamount
WHERE amount - (Select SUM(amountused) from tblamountused) > 0
");
```

Comment: you are using sum() without grouping.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi But there are no other columns in the `SELECT` list, so the group aggregate is assumed to be the whole table.

Comment: Your example has just two of them (which are the same). Does it actually get worse than that?  You can perform a cartesian join against a subquery to get the aggregate values just once, if you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like that:

```
SELECT amount - (Select SUM(amountused) from tblamountused) as amountleft
FROM tblamount
HAVING amountleft > 0
```